# "I can't write on file ..." when installing class from a .ins file

Tags: miktex, installing, document-classes

I'm trying to install the elsarticle class manually on MiKTeX 2.9 (Windows) from the `.ins` file. However, when I type `latex .\elsarticle.ins`, I get the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
! I can't write on file `elsarticle.log'.
Please type another transcript file name:
```

When I type any other file name, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: that is a filesystem restriction not a tex one, you either don't have write access to the current folder or the file is being locked by another program

Comment: If using MiKTeX the packgage installer should have written the file so you should not be trying to fight it check in MiKTeX-console it has been installed and Tasks refresh file name database as admin if you have dual user AND standard user if either. exit MiKTeX-console and reenter to repeat if necessary ALWAYS use console if you can. Never manual install